# PHP template engine which could separate presentation from back logic

Tags: php, html, templates

I am working for a java team now, but I am using PHP for private case.

My work team are importing [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/) which is a powerful template engine for java.

It can write variables for output or expressions such as **if else** into tags as **attributes**, e.g.:

```
<tr th:each="prod : ${allProducts}">  
  <td th:text="${prod.name}">Oranges</td>  
  <td th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(prod.price,1,2)}">0.99</td>  
</tr>
```

It also can render in browser normally and without any java's variables or expression completely.

When I use PHP, I know **Smarty** and **twig**.
But both of them have to write variables and expressions outside of tags(not as attributions), which displaying in browser.

So I want to know whether there is some way to use Smarty or twig as Thymeleaf does.
Or other PHP template engines can do this easily.

Best regards,

**UPDATE**

> It also can render in browser normally and without any java's variables or expression completely.

I mean this can be done without any parse process.
Just only open files in browser as if there is no any engine.

Answer (score 2):

I have got it!

It's [PHPTAL](http://phptal.org/).
Exactly as Thymleaf does!

So wonderful!

Answer (score 0):

Pure PHP with build-in template engine. Nothing to install.

```
<?php foreach ($allProducts as $prod): ?>
<tr>
<td><?= $prod->name ?></td>
<td><?= $numbers->formatDecimal($prod->price,1,2) ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

If You don't enter the `<?` tags, it would be like plain html. The separation is by convention, there are no technical obstacles. If You have experience from more restricted technology, this would be enough.

Comment: Thanks. As a PHP developer, I know this and can use this way without technical obstacles. But when we say separate presentation from logic as possible as we can, I and those designers maybe not like this way.

Answer (score -1):

> But both of them have to write variables and expressions outside of tags

Uhm ... no? I hope i didnt understand you wrong somehow, but this is wrong.

```
<script src="{$tmplpath}js/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{$tmplpath}css/style_general.css">
{if isset($custom_stylesheet)}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{$tmplpath}css/{$custom_stylesheet}">
{/if}
```

This is from my last project where i worked with Smarty, and i dont have to write outside of tags.

Comment: I have never used Thymeleaf, but it appears to be using the (X|HT)ML as part of its syntax. Twig/Smarty operate independently of whatever they're actually outputting, Thymeleaf appears to be more like XSLT.

Comment: @y-u-no-work I am sorry that my description is not very clear, I updated it just now. Well, if your file opened in browser directly, I think the __if__ part still will be displayed.

Comment: @deceze But it is very clean to designers so that they can concentrate on there design.

Comment: Hum, Smarty uses .tpl files which cant even opened in browser directly, he will always try to download it, and yes, you will probably see the if part as plain text. Didnt read that part of it, im sorry.

Comment: @tech_me Sure, I can see the appeal. Not for me personally, since I'm typically the frontend and backend coder in one person, but being able to preview a template as pure HTML without needing an engine to render it through can certainly be advantageous in bigger, more segregated teams.

Comment: @y-u-no-work If you want open it directly in browser, maybe you can change its extension to .html. Then when rendering via CakePHP project, you may change default configuration in order to use .html as Smarty's extension;)